# A question about Legendre polynomials

Tags: polynomials, legendre-polynomials

If $P_n(x)$ is a Legendre polynomial of degree $n$. If a is such that $P_n(a)=0$ that is $a$ is a root of $P_n(x)=0$.
Then the $P_{n-1}(a)$  and $P_{n+1}(a)$ is:
 equal ?
or not equal ?
Or are of opposite signs ?
Or are of the same signs?

Which one is correct?

I think " not equal " is correct

Comment: Please don't repost [old questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3639847/question-on-legendre-polynomials/3639874?noredirect=1#comment7479973_3639874).

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: The Legendre polynomials satisfy the following recurrence relation (by Bonnet)
$$
(n+1)P_{n+1}(x)=(2n+1)xP_n(x)-nP_{n-1}(x).
$$